# How to keep thread alive when use close application via swiping

Tags: android, multithreading, swipe

I have a thread in my application's result page. And it's calculating the values every minute. 
My problem is when user close application via swiping from recent applications, thread is stopping. But it must work.

I know i could create a service-intentservice for it, but that is my first application and i wrote lots of code about that tread, also that thread changes the values at result activity page. So that will be a togh operation for me.

I looked for it so much but i couldnt find an answer. Can you please give me an advise if i can keep that thread alive easily?

Thanks

Comment: "also that thread changes the values at result activity page" -- there is no "result activity page" after the user clears your task. That activity will have been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

**Put your thread in a foreground `Service`**

Normally, the entire VM is killed when a user swipes your app out of recents.  But in recent versions of Android, foreground services are not killed.  (Thanks to [Steve M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817031/steve-m) for bringing this change to my attention.)  On older versions of Android, even foreground services were killed.  This was [considered a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313).  Unfortunately, Google is notorious for inappropriately closing issues as "obsolete," so there's no way to know when it was actually fixed except by testing different devices.  (Or even whether it was deliberately fixed at all, or accidentally fixed as a result of some other change.)  I'm fairly certain that foreground services were killed in Android 4.4.  They are not killed in Android 5.1, at least on my devices, including one that used to be running 4.4.  But note the comments on that bug report about foreground services being killed in 5.1 and 6.0.  It may be that this was never truly fixed, and it's still hit or miss.

Note that regardless of whether the VM is killed, the foreground service's [`onTaskRemoved(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) will always be called.  (At least in my testing.)

You can test whether the VM is being killed by putting this code in an activity:

```
private static final long vmInitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

// in onCreate(...)
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView)).setText(new Date(vmInitTime).toString());
```

The displayed time will not change as long as the same VM is running.  (Or to be more precise, as long as the same definition of your activity class exists.  In practice, the `ClassLoader` has the same lifetime as the VM.)

Comment: "When the user swipes your task out of recents, the whole VM and OS-level process are killed" - that's not true on many devices, perhaps the majority.

Comment: Krumwide Looks like you are correct for most cases, however if there is foreground service running in the app process the process will not be killed.

Comment: @SteveM It looks like you're right on 5.1, though it used to be the case that even foreground services were killed.  This was [considered a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313).  Google is notorious for inappropriately closing issues as "obsolete", so there's no telling exactly when it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the thread in a foreground service, if it makes sense to be displaying a notification to the user. In this case the service will continue to you run on many devices, as long as the device is not force-stopping the app.